# How to download the whole BLAST nt database into a specific folder?

Tags: blast, data-download

I have successfully downloaded the whole nt BLAST database into the current folder using:

```
wget -b "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt.??.tar.gz"
```

However, I would like to download it in a specific folder, e.g. output/

I have tried:

```
wget -b "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt.??.tar.gz"  -O output/
```

but it does not work. Nothing happens. My 'wget-log' is empty.

I could move to that folder and download it there but I would like to remain in the same working directory.

C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-O` is to specify the name of the output *file.* You want the [`-P`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078524/how-to-specify-the-location-with-wget) option.

So, from your example

```
wget -b "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/nt.??.tar.gz" -P output/
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using NCBI's tool for this called `update_blastdb.pl`, shipped with the blast suite (I use the conda environment from [bioconda](https://bioconda.github.io/recipes/blast/README.html?highlight=blast#package-package%20%27blast%27)).

`cd` to the directory you want nt DB in and run:

```sh
update_blastdb.pl --decompress nt
```

Pros: if a download fails for whatever reason it is retried, downloads are md5sum checked and re-running in a folder with an existing DB will (as the name suggests) only update the relevant DB portions. More information [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK569850/)!